# How to pass 'YYYY-MM-DD' date format to postgresql trough prisma client?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, nestjs, prisma

I have a `nestjs` app using `prisma`, with following `postgresql` table:

```
Table "public.Transaction"
Column |       Type        |               
-------+-------------------+
id     | integer           |
amount | double precision  |
date   | date              |
```

In prisma, I defined the table as this:

```
model Transaction {
  id                Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  amount            Float   
  date              DateTime @db.Date
```

Since I am using `postgresql`, I need to pass a date with `'YYYY-MM-DD'` format.

I am trying to pass this format as a string:

```
const createdTransaction = await this.prisma.transaction.create({
  data: {
    amount: 3333,
    date: '2022-11-22',
  },
});
```

But I get following error:

```
Argument date: Got invalid value '2022-11-22' on prisma.createOneTransaction. Provided String, expected DateTime.
```

I know I have to pass a Date type, but using the javascript formatting, everything ends up in a string.

What value should I pass to date within `nestjs`?

Because if I use `new Date(2022,11,22)`, it is accepted by `prisma`, but this is stored as `Thu Dec 22 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)`, a string, which is not what `postgresql` expects.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just make the type of the date column string in your Transaction model.

This way you can pass the date string to PostgreSQL.

Another way is maybe to make the type number and pass the milliseconds date to PostgreSQL.

In your service before returning the object or in your frontend you can
parse the date back to a string.

Comment: Milliseconds won't turn into a date without additional calculations and/or parsing. Use the ISO 8601 standard to avoid this.

Comment: I thought about using strings, but since I'm new to the prisma and nest ecosystem, didn't know if that was the way

Comment: But then, in my postgresql db, the date column is of type string, which is not combinient

Comment: Because then it can be tricky to work with date greater than and so on

Comment: No, in Postgres I think you can keep the type of the column  date and then it will convert the string you pass into a date